# Wired wrong /fixed / now all switches out

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, smoke

I have a switch plate with 4 light switches. One switch covers three pendant lights. I rewired a new pendant light and turned on switch and there was a puff of smoke. I realized I accidentally connected black to ground. I fixed my error. Went to breaker box. Breaker had flipped. I flipped the breaker back on and now there are no lights for 3 of the 4 switches on the group. The breaker is fine and I don’t know where to troubleshoot next.

Comment: Start with uploading a picture showing all wires to all switches.

Comment: there is probably a GFCI somewhere that powers those switches. You may need to hunt it down and reset it.

Comment: Smoke means something melted and burned

Comment: ... and may be more likely to do so again if the burning removed some of the insulation. You need to find and examine the burned spot.